# Dependency check in SonarQube

Tags: dependencies, sonarqube, version

We have upgraded from SonarQube version 5.1.2 to SonarQube version 5.6.6. After upgrading am unable to find the dependency checking feature (dependent files/ dependent class) in 5.6.6 which existed in 5.1.2. Is there any way/solution to achieve the same in higher version on SoanrQube 5.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Features related to dependencies were dropped in 5.2 with no replacement because they served only a very narrow slice of users (Java + Maven) and because they seemed rarely used.

Comment: Hello Ann, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The reason why we have upgraded the SonarQube version is because C# plugin is supported from version 5.6 only. So If I understood correctly, there is no other alternate way for dependency check in SonarQube 5.6

Comment: Sorry, no. But dependency checking wasn't available for C# anyway.

Comment: Ann, We are checking whether is there any possibility to replicate the Class coupling feature of Visual Studio for C# which is equivalent to dependency class in SonarQube.